# libpqxx on raspberry pi

Tags: qt, c++11, ubuntu-14.04, raspberry-pi3, libpqxx

I have a desktop(ubuntu 14.04 64 bit) QT application which uses libpqxx(c++ library for Postgres). The GUI app is an interface to the postgress database and does a lot of operations. Now, I am trying to port this application to a raspberry pi3. I started with a test QT app. Used cross-compile tool chain to build the test app on desktop and deployed it on pi. It works like a charm. However, when I follow the same steps to deploy my actual app on pi, its giving me compile time error

```
fatal error: pqxx/pqxx: No such file directory.
```

I have the library linked in .pro file via -lpqxx -lpq. I have also installed libpqxx on pi3. It works on my desktop with Qt 5.6.1 GCC 64 bit kit but doesn't work on pi with Rpi3 Qt kit. Please help.

New Edit:

I added pqxx library path in my .pro file. It looks like this now :

```
target.path = /home/pi
INSTALLS +=target
unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lpqxx
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../usr/local/include/pqxx
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../usr/local/include/pqxx
unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../usr/local/lib/libpqxx.a
```

The previous error is gone. However, it gives me this error now:

```
/home/pragya/ep/PHOENIX/GUI/LUXE_GUI/../../../../../../usr/local/lib//libpqxx.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: When you import a library you use `-L/path/of/your_library -libyour_library`, in your case you must indicate the path of the raspberry library that should be in your HOST.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I appreciate any further help.

Comment: how do I install libpbxx?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libpqxx-4.0

Comment: delete `unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS ....`

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Should I include pqxx library path of the pi in my host QT?

Comment: You have to have that library in your HOST, that is your PC.

Comment: To be clear, you must install it in raspberry pi with sudo apt-get install ..., then copy it to your PC since you need it there to compile it, the .so from ubuntu is different from the raspberry since the raspberry is an ARM in change your PC should be intel or AMD so there is no compatibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171261/discussion-between-minion-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Let me go through the process. On raspberry pi I ran- sudo apt-get install libpqxx-dev. It installed the library in /usr/lib/libpqxx.a and I copied it from pi to HOST:/usr/local/lib. Also, I copied /usr/share/include/pqxx from pi to HOST:/usr/local/include/ . Then I am attaching the path of the library and include path to Qt .pro. Compiling it and it is giving error "undefined references".

Comment: You're wrong, when you do a cross-compiler you must have a folder where the libraries and resources of Rpi are, that's called sysroot, inside sysroot there should be a folder called usr/local/lib